`504 Gateway Time-out` when sending emails with Djoser and Django in production
I am encountering an issue in my Django production environment when using Djoser for user registration and login management. When a user requests to create an account, the API takes about a minute and then returns a 504 Gateway Time-out error. In my local environment, the process works correctly, and the activation email is sent without issues.
What I've Tried:

Increased timeout options in Nginx
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location /static {
        alias /vol/web/static;
    }


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;

        # new code
        uwsgi_read_timeout       300s; 
        proxy_read_timeout       300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout    300s;
        proxy_send_timeout       300s;
    }
}



This change the error. Now after more than 2 minutes I receive the error Server Error (500) but I still don't receive the email. It's important to note that locally I receive the email almost instantly.

Added logs in the email-sending function.
class ActivationEmail(email.ActivationEmail):
    template_name = "user/email/activation.html"

    def send(self, to, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Sending activation mail to {to}")
        try:
            super().send(to, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(f"Couldn't send mail to {to}")
            raise
        print(f"Activation mail sent successfully to {to}")



The function appears to be called correctly but the super().send(to, *args, **kwargs) never returns.
I also checked environment variables to ensure they are consistent between local and production environments. The email configuration is the same both locally and in production. However, in production, the email does not arrive in the inbox, and the 504 or 500 error persists.
I think the error came from nginx since locally I have no nginx configuration. That's is the major difference between the two environments. But until now the changes I did in timeout options in nginx just changed the error, without solving the issue.
Question:
What could be causing the 504 error and 500 error when sending emails in production? Are there any additional configurations I should check in Nginx or in my email settings? How can I diagnose and resolve this issue?
